# C# How to config HotKey to rename automatically function/prop/variable

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I changed my computer recently and I forgot how configure my VS to automatically show the smart tag context menu to rename a method / variable / etc:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hotkey command that I been searching `View.ShowSmartTag`:

[image: Solution]

Hope that be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do :

Ctrl + R + R

Comment: After renaming it this way it will rename all applicable variables automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366756(v=vs.90).aspx) for a list of VS shortcuts including Refactor.Rename.